# change $location search preventing push to history

Tags: angularjs

I have a `router view` with `reloadOnSearch: false`, it is a *search* page.

When entering without any search parameter I attempt to set some defaults:

entering in: `#/search`

I set defaults pars: `#/search?currpage=1&pagesize=20`
using `$location.search({currpage:1,pagesize:20})` the job is done, but I also get the new url pushed in the history, which is as expected, but in this special case it breaks the logic of the navigation flow (clicking back button gets to `#/search` and again sets defaults and pushes)

Is there a way to *replace* the search string preventing the history push?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried to you use the dedicated [replace()](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) method ? It prevent to add an history record :

```
$location.search({currpage:1,pagesize:20}).replace()
```

Never used it after a `$location.search()` but it definitely works on `$location.path()`

Comment: That's what i needed, thanks! .. i don't know why did i missed it, it's the method described right after `search` in the docs! .. anyway it's really flexible as it _marks for replace_ all the changes to the path made in the current digest cycle, so it's not mandatory to invoke it _after_ the `search` or `path` call, it can be invoked even before the changes

Comment: This is a lifesaver! +1

Comment: This saved my life. Thank you.